# $\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{\frac{1+x-y-xy}{1-x+y-xy}} \, dx\,dy $

Tags: calculus

please hint me solve the problem.I don't have idea to solve it.

$$\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-1}^1
   \sqrt{\frac{1+x-y-xy}{1-x+y-xy}} \,dx\,dy
$$

Comment: This is equivalent to $$\iint_{[-1,1]^2} \sqrt{\frac{(1+x)(1-y)}{(1-x)(1+y)}} dxdy$$, and the latter integral clearly has issues at $x=1$ and $y=-1$ -- are you sure it exists?

Comment: The integral exist and equal to $\pi^2$

Answer (score 5):

Separate the integral:

$$\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-1}^1
   \sqrt{\frac{1+x-y-xy}{1-x+y-xy}} \,dx\,dy
= \int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}} \,dx \times
  \int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{\frac{1-y}{1+y}} \,dy
$$
and now integrate each one by one. I believe you can do one by parts and then use a trig substitution for each one.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $x=\cos2\theta$ and then do something similar for the $y$ integral